# All links with one class - how to add additional class on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, toggleclass

It is possible if i have more links with the same class, on click add aditional class for active item? I have tried with jquery '.toggleClass()' but if i click on next link then both links has the same class

```
<a href="link1.html">1</a>
<a href="link2.html">2</a>
<a href="link3.html">3</a>
```

I have tried:

```
$('a').click(function() { 
    $('a').toggleClass('active'); 
});
```

Comment: Please show your code. I.e. what have you tried?

Comment: try removin the class in other elements and add the appropriate class to the clicked one .

Comment: I have tried so:

`
$('a').click(function() {
$('a').toggleClass('active');
});
`

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17588791/edit) it into your question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any class in your html, but I add some for a example. Try this:

html

```
<div class="menu">
<a href="link1.html">1</a>
<a href="link2.html">2</a>
<a href="link3.html">3</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.menu a').click(function(){ //check thru all <a> elements  inside .menu
    $('.menu ').removeClass("active"); // remove all active class    
    $(this).addClass("active"); //put active in parent of <a> which was clicked
});
```

Comment: @MirkoSimic, nice to hear! Please click to accept the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this`:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('a.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

So, when an anchor is clicked, toggle the `active` class on that given anchor, and remove the `active` class from all siblings which are anchors and have the `active` class.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/295zX/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the addClass() method

```
$('.link').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RKjh7/1/

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('yourClass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon clicking on one of the links, remove the active class from current link, and add to the link just clicked.

```
    $('a').click(function()
    {
       $('.active').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the active class from all link and then add it on the clicked element.

Try this :

```
jQuery('.link').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var elem = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('.link').removeClass('active');
    elem.addClass('active');

});
```

**[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kJpGN/)**